# Error after upgrading ASP.Net WebAPI nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, asp.net-web-api2

I have updated my WebApi nuget package from 5.2.2 to 5.2.3 and I started getting this error,

> The type 'System.Web.Http.ApiController' exists in both 'c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
>   4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll' and
>   '\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll'

I tried cleaning the solution/deleting reference and stuff but I could not get it working. Please help.

Update#:
Reverting all the packages helped. But still not sure if I missed something in the upgrade.

Comment: Been through similar countless times (errors that _seem_ to make sense, others, just off the wall), so this my "sanity check" : After updating packages, before doing _anything_, just close and restart (solution and VS). If symptoms persist, only then do I tinker further. Also, check on that pesky "license update for Windows Store" - top right red flag. **If its there**, chances are good that it will spawn nightmares.  Hth.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when getting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.

At Nuget Package Manager Console write this:

```
 Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProjectNameGoesHere' -Reinstall
```

This will update all your packages and it will solve your problem.I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes with upgrades, another solution could be, close your solution and delete the content of **packages** folder of your solution , except **repositories.config** , uninstall the **WebApi package  and dependencies** and install the newest version. 
In some cases you need fix the assemblyBinding in web.config.